# concat array of array after each 4 index

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, foreach, transformation

i've data in this format

```
[["hi, hello, "bye"],["hi, hello, "bye"],["hi, hello, "bye"],["hi, hello, "bye"],["hi, hello, "bye"],["hi, hello, "bye"],["hi, hello, "bye"],["hi, hello, "bye"]]
```

and i want to concate 4 index to new array so new array will be

```
[["hi, hello, "bye","hi, hello, "bye","hi, hello, "bye","hi, hello, "bye"],["hi, hello, "bye","hi, hello, "bye","hi, hello, "bye","hi, hello, "bye"]]
```

i am trying with this code but not sure how to do

```
const table = document.querySelectorAll('table[class=ProductInventory]')[1];
    const data = [];
    const finalData =[]

    for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
        var tableRow = table.rows[i];
        var rowData = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < tableRow.cells.length; j++) {
            rowData.push(tableRow.cells[j].innerText);
        }
        data.push(rowData);
    } 
   let counter = 1
    for (var a = 0; a <= data.length / 4; a++) {
            const obj = []
            counter++
            if(counter == 4){
                obj.concat(data[a-3], data[a - 2], data[a - 1]);
                counter = 0
            }
            
            finalData.push(obj)
        }
```

Comment: There's no point in calling [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) if you don't use the array it returns.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.from` along with `Array#slice`.

```js
const arr = [["hi", "hello", "bye"],["hi", "hello", "bye"],["hi", "hello", "bye"],["hi", 'hello', "bye"],["hi", 'hello', "bye"],["hi", 'hello', "bye"],["hi", 'hello', "bye"],["hi", 'hello', "bye"]];
const size = 4;
const res = Array.from({length: Math.ceil(arr.length / size)}, 
    (_,i)=>arr.slice(i * size, (i + 1) * size).flat());
console.log(res);
```

Comment: @HimanshuTak Would you mind [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) my answer if it solved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

you can use JavaScript Array `reduce()` Method

```
const data = [["hi", "hello", "bye"],["hi", "hello", "bye"],["hi", "hello", "bye"],["hi", 'hello', "bye"],["hi", 'hello', "bye"],["hi", 'hello', "bye"],["hi", 'hello', "bye"],["hi", 'hello', "bye"]];
const finalData = data.reduce((finalVal, currenctVal, currenctIndex) => {
    let index = Math.floor(currenctIndex / 4);
    if(!finalVal[index]) {
       finalVal[index] = [];
    }
    finalVal[index] = finalVal[index].concat(currenctVal);
    return finalVal;
     
},[]);
```